# How to get Token in Identity after login using Form Authentication

Tags: c#, access-token, asp.net-identity

I set up a Cookie Authentication as well as Token Based Authentication for Web API.
After I successfully log in, I am loading SPA which of course makes several API calls to the server.

But how can I get a Token before making those calls? I'm not sure what to do, and need some suggestions on this.

Comment: which version of webapi?

Comment: I am pretty sure if you set up authentication correctly then once a user is authenticated then you just decorate the server methods with either [Authorize] or [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] the authentication should handle the cookies and throw an exception when not authorized. You could have your login return a token that is good for a session or get it from the cookie. On the server side you can use Thread.Current.User for identity.

Comment: As it is mentioned I am using Token Authentication for Web Api, so it will require valid Token when I place "Authorize" attribute on it. In order to get token I need to post user credential to the Owin Middleware exposed endpoint i.e, /Token but I setup a Cookie Authentication for Login. So, when user login it will load the SPA, which will require Token to make API calls, so how will I get the Token in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make a call to the `/Token/` endpoint to get the token

you can get details from the [MS page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

From that page:

you first need to register a user at the url:

```
http://localhost:port/api/Account/Register
```

with a body like

```
{
    "UserName": "Alice",
    "Password": "password123",
    "ConfirmPassword": "password123"
}
```

The you need to do a POST to get the token. Change the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Replace the request body with the following:

```
grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}
```

and you should get a response like

```
{
    "access_token":"boQtj0SCGz2GFGz[...]",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":1209599,
    "userName":"Alice",
    ".issued":"Mon, 14 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT",
    ".expires":"Mon, 28 Oct 2013 06:53:32 GMT"
}
```

Comment: But how do I get username and password at that page? This is the main issue I have, because when I login it completely transfer to the new page which load the SPA.

Comment: The only thing I need to know where do I get user credential after login? Obviously /Token end point require it to produce Token.

Comment: what do you mean 'user credential'?  The username and password the user entered?  you need to capture those at the client side I think...

Comment: I am using form authentication for Register/Login and other stuff. So you can assume that, when my SPA loads, user already being authenticated

Comment: Did you get my scenario? Any suggestion please